# Process data from BigQuery using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, dataflow

I want to retrieve data from BigQuery that arrived every hour and do some processing and pull the new calculate variables in a new BigQuery table. The things is that I've never worked with gcp before and I have to for my job now.
I already have my code in python to process the data but it's work only with a "static" dataset

Comment: Ok, you get the data from BigQuery and after? Where are you storing them? Other question: Does your calculation can be done in SQL language?

Comment: First thank you mate. I want to do some processing on this data with some condition and calculation, I want to store them in another table on BigQuery. I don't know if it's possible in SQL because there are many process to do. So if I summarize that's the schema : BigQuery ==> some processing ==> BigQuery (another table)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about your architecture? How is your data loaded the first BigQuery? Do you have a single table ir many tables?

Comment: @rmesteves No problem, I have only one table, it's not a personnal project so I can't say from where the data arrived but I can only access by BigQuery, I can't have access before. So The data come to BigQuery periodically

Comment: Great. Would a scheduled transformation work for you? With scheduled I mean, running every 2 hours or any other pre determined period

Comment: Of course it's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your source and sink of that are both in `BigQuery`, I would recommend you to do your transformations inside `BigQuery`.
If you need a scheduled job that runs in a pre determined time, you can use [Scheduled Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).

With Scheduled Queries you are able to save some query, execute it periodically and save the results to another table.

To create a scheduled query follow the steps:

1. In BigQuery Console, write your query
2. After writing the correct query, click in **Schedule query** and then in **Create new scheduled query** as you can see in the image below

[image]

3. Pay attention in this two fields:

   - **Schedule options**: there are some pre-configured schedules such as daily, monthly, etc.. If you need to execute it every two hours, for example, you can set the **Repeat** option as **Custom** and set your **Custom schedule** as '*every 2 hours*'. In the **Start date and run time** field, select the time and data when your query should start being executed.
   - **Destination for query results**: here you can set the dataset and table where your query's results will be saved. Please keep in mind that this option is not available if you use [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting). In other words, you should use only SQL and not scripting in your transformations.

[image]

4. Click on **Schedule**

After that your query will start being executed according to your schedule and destination table configurations.

Comment: I think I don't have the knowledge to do it in sql beacause there are many condition to apply and some calculation, is there any way to do it ? I'm most a "programmer" than sql developper if you know what I mean by that

Comment: @just_work in this approach you will need to use some SQL one way or another. If some kind of coding help you, you can take a look in the JavaScript user defined functions (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-examples)

Comment: Thank you I will see how can I do that

Comment: @just_work you're welcome :)  In the end if it helps you or solve your problem, consider upvoting or accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

According with Google recommendation, when your data are in BigQuery and when you want to transform them to store them in BigQuery, it's always quicker and cheaper to do this in BigQuery if you can express your processing in SQL.

That's why, I don't recommend you dataflow for your use case. If you don't want, or you can't use directly the SQL, you can create [User Defined Function (UDF) in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) in Javascript.

**EDIT**

If you have no information when the data are updated into BigQuery, Dataflow won't help you on this. Dataflow can process realtime data only if these data are present into PubSub. If not, it's not magic!!

Because you haven't the information of when a load is performed, you have to run your process on a schedule. For this, [Scheduled Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) is the right solution is you use BigQuery for your processing.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, so i'm new on gcp and I don't know how to do it, is it on dataflow ? How can I execute my script when the data arrive ( it arrive in batch every 1 or 2 hours), thank you a lot

Comment: Where the data arrive? In Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: No, in Big Query

Comment: Which process loads the data into BigQuery? Is it possible this process publish a message into PubSub?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any access of this process, so I just have access to the data by BigQuery

Comment: I updated my answer with a trigger on a schedule with scheduled queries of BigQuery.